# What does Artifactory consider to be a privileged user?

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to use [Artifactory Copy Item REST API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CopyItem) with an admin user but it's (quietly) failing with:

```
User doesn't have permissions to create... Needs write permissions.
```

The documentation says a privileged user is required, but I'm unable to find anything describing what that actually means and there's no `privileged` setting in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Copying is really comprised of two operations:

1. Read from the source.
2. Write to the target.

So the subject you authenticate with must have a ***read*** permission on the source repository, and a ***deploy*** permission on the target repository.

Comment: The user is able to read an existing item from the source repository then put a modified copy of the item to the destination repository.